# How to POST with AFNetworking and send parameters as POST Data?

Tags: ios, swift, post, afnetworking, instagram

I'm trying to make a POST on the Instagram API to change a user's relationship but I'm having trouble getting the call to work. I've done some research and one guy says to put the `action=follow` part in the `POST Data`. I searched this further and still cannot get my requests to go through.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/\(user.id)/relationship?access_token=\(account.accessToken)")!)
        let key = "action=follow"
        let mastData = key.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!
        let mastLength = "\(mastData.length)"

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = mastData
        request.addValue(mastLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let operation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: request)
        operation.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
        operation.setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({ (_, result) -> Void in
                        let result = result as! NSDictionary
                        let data = result["data"] as! NSDictionary

                        completion(true)
            }) { (_, error) -> Void in
                completion(false)
        }
```

Also, I know the `user.id` is valid and the `account.accessToken` is valid also because I'm using them successfully in other parts of the app.

Comment: You should provide some info as to what you expect to see and what you actually get. This is in order to understand if you have a problem with your function or with Instagram APIs

Comment: Did you call `.start()` on the operation?

Comment: Yes, I did that was the next line

Comment: @shakked so what exactly do you mean by "I'm having trouble"? Does this code crash? Is completion handler not called? Or do you get an error returned? If so, have you tried print() to see which type of error you are getting? I don't mean this in a bad way, but you should give some more clues as to what your actual problem is :)